# PL/SQL Package invalidated

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a script that makes use of a package (PKG_MY_PACKAGE). I will change some of the fields in a query in that package and then recompile it (I don't change or compile any other packages). I run the script and I get an error that looks like

```
    ORA-04068: existing state of packages has been discarded
    ORA-04061: existing state of package body "USER3.PKG_MY_PACKAGE" has been invalidated
    ORA-04065: not executed, altered or dropped package body "USER3.PKG_MY_PACKAGE"
    ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "USER3.PKG_MY_PACKAGE"
    ORA-06512: at line 34
```

I run the script again (without changing anything else in the system) and the script executes successfully.

I thought that when I compiled before I executed the script that would fix any invalid references. This is 100% reproducible, and the more I use this script the more annoying it gets. What could cause this, and what would fix it?

(oracle 10g, using PL/SQL Developer 7)

Comment: @OMG: I'm only recompiling the body because that's all that changes.

Comment: There is no reason for you to use global variables for this - just switch to sys_context. This way you can completely remove global variables and make your package stateless.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Background**

`existing state of packages has been discarded` means, that your Package (or Body) had some sort of state, which was lost by a recompilation.

This is caused by a global variable stored in your Package.
Until 11.2.0.2, constants did also cause this behavior (see [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/whatsnew.htm#LNPLS110)).

Since the package had already been used in your session, Oracle assumes that this state is relevant for you. Some variables might have changed, and when you recompile, the values are reset.

This exception is thrown, so that your clients know that they can't rely on those variables any more.

**Solutions**

- Call again, being aware that the state has been reset
- Close your session and reconnect before calling the package again.
- Reset the state manually (see [Paul James' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2506333/17343))

**Solutions (changing source)**

- Remove all global variables (and constants *before 11gR2)* if possible

  - Move them to the Package Header so at least a recompilation of the Body works
- Replace global variables by `DETERMINISTIC` functions (as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6456680/17343))
- Defining packages with [`PRAGMA SERIALLY_REUSABLE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/seriallyreusable_pragma.htm) causes Oracle to re-initialize the global variables with every call to the server.

Comment: Indeed, I do have some globals! I'll see if I can find a way around that, maybe make them non-globals... Is there a way to have static values for procedures in PL/SQL?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "static values for procedures"? Those global variables are more or less static variables (per session). The easiest work-around for you would be to put the global variables in the Package Header instead of the Body - state will not be invalidated any more when compiling the Body. Why do you need those globals?

Comment: They hold configuration values that only need to be set once and drive the rest of the system. I didn't want to put them into the header because I didn't want any other code to have access to them (they get passed into the one relevant procedure from a script). I suppose they could be stored in a table, but there could be a LOT of reads on that table if I did it.

Comment: Guess I would have put configuration into the Body too. Reading it from a table might slow down your process. Are you still going to recompile your Body in future or is this only now for testing? One other way would be to define a `RECORD` containing all necessary variables and pass it to the procedures that you call.

Comment: I think for now I will just read from the table. I've rewritten part of the affected code so I don't think it will have too many reads, so probably not major performance problem now. I'm only going through all this recompiling for dev/test, so this shouldn't be an issue in production systems.

Comment: I just restarted the IIS to fix the issue.

Answer (score 26):

If you're running stuff in a script try these commands in there prior to running the re-compiled code..

```
exec DBMS_SESSION.RESET_PACKAGE
exec DBMS_SESSION.MODIFY_PACKAGE_STATE( DBMS_SESSION.REINITIALIZE )
```

They do what the name might suggest.

Comment: Interesting... I'll have to try this.

Comment: Man, I wish I could mark two answers as the accepted answer. One of the other devs here said this works fine, and it means I don't have to worry about re-writing and re-testing code.

Answer (score 2):

Possible issues you can have is:

- The package/procedure you are calling is invalid (though it can work if called independently)
  check this query whether you have an entry of your package or objects used in your package in this **all_objects** view

```sql
select * from all_objects where status = 'INVALID' and owner = 'SCHEMA_NAME';
```

- Check your package is having global variables? if yes then check if those variable is not being changed by any other session preferable remove those global variables/use function
- Run below script to compile all the objects in your schema

```sql
begin
   dbms_utility.compile_schema('SCHEMA_NAME', false); 
end;
```

- Last option if none of the above works then remove all the procedures/function from your package, add new function and try to run your function from the trigger. check if this works then your package is in special lock. After adding a new function/proc it's state will be valid again and then you can add all your actual funcs/procs and remove the newly added function/proc.

Answer (score 0):

The above error : ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called.

is caused when an attempt was made to call a stored program that could not be found. The program may have been dropped or incompatibly modified, or have compiled with errors.

Check that all referenced programs, including their package bodies,    exist and are compatible.

You can run this query to find invalid objects, which may cause the ORA-06508 error:

select 
   comp_id, 
   comp_name, 
   version, 
   status, 
   namespace, 
   schema 
from 
   dba_registry;

Comment: This reads like it was copied directly from an Oracle documentation web page.